# How to generate firebase uid

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to store data (not users) in a Firebase backend. How do I generate Firebase unique identifer and store it in the child? I have been using firebase (DatabaseReference Key) as the unique identifier of a record nut the key is null.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `push().getKey()` to get the unique key

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
String key = database.getReference("todoList").push().getKey();

Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
childUpdates.put( key, todo.toFirebaseObject());
database.getReference("todoList").updateChildren(childUpdates, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
        if (databaseError == null) {

        }
    }
});
```

This is explained in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data#save_data_as_transactions) under **Update specific fields** section

> This example uses push() to create a post in the node containing posts
>   for all users at /posts/$postid and simultaneously retrieve the key
>   with getKey(). The key can then be used to create a second entry in
>   the user's posts at /user-posts/$userid/$postid.

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
String key = database.getReference("todoList").push().getKey();

Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
childUpdates.put( key, todo.toFirebaseObject());
database.getReference("todoList").updateChildren(childUpdates, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
        if (databaseError == null) {

        }
    }
});
```